# htmlbegin form id not found using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, razor, model-view-controller

I have a simple webpage with using an Html.BeginForm statement.

I have applied id and name attributes to it, but when I try to use jQuery to find the form, it is not visible in intellisense, or found when I run the page in a browser.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "QueuedItems", FormMethod.Get, 
                         new { id = "abc1" }))
{
function performSearch(){
$("#abc1").submit()}
    }
```

Any ideas welcome.

Comment: How and where are you calling performSearch()? And have you checked the rendered HTML to see if it created the form tag the way you expected?

Comment: Hi ADyson, This is just the cut down form to show the essentials. The problem I really want an answer to is why the id of the form is not showing in intellisense, but the other id's of objects on the form, such as a button and datetime picker do show.

Comment: Are the button and datepicker that you mention created using raw HTML, or Razor? I would guess that the JS intellisense can't predict what the HTML output of the Razor code will be.